# Issue with socket.io when hosting on Heroku

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a problem when uplaoding my code server to Heroku. There is no socket connexion message.
This is the code of the server side on Heroku

```
var appS = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(appS);
var io = require('socket.io')(http,{path: '/octagon/socket.io'});
http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});


io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) { 

  socket.on('test',function (message) {

    console.log(message)
  })
})
```

And this is the code for client

```
var socket  = io.connect('https://murmuring-waters-83521.herokuapp.com/',
                {
                    reconnect: true,
                    transports : ['websocket'],
                    ressources: '/octagon/socket.io'
                });
```

I Still get this message

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://murmuring-waters-83521.herokuapp.com/octagon/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 503
```

Comment: ongoing discussion here, those who are interested, please join :)  https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177915/123123122

Comment: is there a reason why you need to adjust the path where socket.io client is served? i removed `/octagon/socket.io` on server & client - added `rejectUnauthorized: false` option on client & it's working. You can also omit `transports : ['websocket'],` since it will auto upgrade to `websocket` if it's available, this way you can support more devices

Comment: sample site that's working https://calm-brushlands-46230.herokuapp.com/

Comment: There is no reason to ajust the path of socket.io. I saw this in a forum and I tried to implement it

Comment: i posted an answer. can you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this to work by updating the client config

```
var socket  = io('//murmuring-waters-83521.herokuapp.com',
  {
      reconnect: true,
      rejectUnauthorized: false, // new
      path: '/octagon/socket.io' // use this instead of `ressources`
  });
  socket.on('connection', function () {
    alert('Browser is connected to server!');
  });
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177949/discussion-on-answer-by-theo-issue-with-socket-io-when-hosting-on-heroku).

Comment: Thanks @Theo this code work for me https://gist.github.com/shierro/66171abeda461c8f7f03383fd639e8b8